# Hide a box if it doesn't contain an image

Tags: html, jquery

I have several DIVs containing images generated from database.
However, there is a DIV doesn't contain any image, but `<img>`.  I need to hide this DIV, but somehow my jquery code doesn't work!

Please take a look at my sample code and give me a hand.

Thanks!

```js
$(function() {
$('.image-box').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).attr('src') == '') {
    $(this).hide();
  }
})
})
```

```css
.image-box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 180px;
  height: 130px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-box">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTgjelULwWqZnw17bVmdar736yVvV8J7ie5ntx9QFbW&s">
</div>
<div class="image-box">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTgjelULwWqZnw17bVmdar736yVvV8J7ie5ntx9QFbW&s">
</div>
<div class="image-box">
<img>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.image-box')` selects the div. You then let the function look for an attribute 'src' on that div. Try `if ( $(this).find('img').attr('src') == '')`.

Comment: @Skip, Thank you for your code!  It looks right, I replaced your code, but somehow it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the wrong element to get the `src` attr, you should get the children of the currently selected div. The below code works.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".image-box").each(function (index, item) {

    if (
      typeof $(this).children().attr("src") == "undefined" ||
      $(this).children().attr("src") == ""
    ) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.image-box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 180px;
  height: 130px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-box">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTgjelULwWqZnw17bVmdar736yVvV8J7ie5ntx9QFbW&s">
</div>
<div class="image-box">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTgjelULwWqZnw17bVmdar736yVvV8J7ie5ntx9QFbW&s">
</div>
<div class="image-box">
<img>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me my error and your correction!

Comment: Glad to see it helped you, happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

Check for the `src` attribute of any of the `img` elements in `this`:

```js
$(function() {
 $('.image-box').each(function() {
  if (!$("img",this).attr('src')) $(this).hide();
 })
})
```

```css
.image-box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 180px;
  height: 130px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-box">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTgjelULwWqZnw17bVmdar736yVvV8J7ie5ntx9QFbW&s">
</div>
<div class="image-box">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTgjelULwWqZnw17bVmdar736yVvV8J7ie5ntx9QFbW&s">
</div>
<div class="image-box">
<img>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Carsten Massmann, Thank you very much for your code, that works well!  Would you please explain how `("img",this)` works?

Comment: `$("img",this)` is simply a shortcut notation for `$(this).find("img")`. `.find("img")` will find any direct or indirect children of the current jQuery selection.